# How to refresh markers on Map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to refresh `markers` in map,my map contains different locations with current location. if server side add any location then add that marker in my map.

How can I refresh my markers without load map ?

My code

```
if(arl.size()!=0){
                for(int j = 0;j<arl.size();j++){


              String lat =arl.get(j).get("lat").toString();
              String lng =arl.get(j).get("lng").toString();
              if ( !lat.trim().equals("") && !lng.trim().equals("") ) {
              double Hlat = Double.parseDouble(lat.trim());
              double Hlong= Double.parseDouble(lng.trim());

              LatLng dabaseLocations =new LatLng(Hlat, Hlong);

              Marker HYD = _googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()

              .position(dabaseLocations)
              .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
              .flat(true));

              // Show current location with database locations

              _googleMap.clear();
                _googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition)); 
                Marker m=_googleMap.addMarker(new   
         MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("start"));
               // m.setPosition(new LatLng(5,5));

                 }
               }

         }
             else{

                 // Show only Current Location

            _googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition)); 
            _googleMap.addMarker(new     
       MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("start"));

        }
```

Comment: You have to clear the map and then add the markers according to the new data.

Comment: ya i wrote _googleMap.clear(); this but not working

Comment: Why are you adding the marker 'HYD' before clearing the google map?? Do you have to show only two markers or more than two ??

Comment: no i want to show all markers with current location

Comment: add this line  _googleMap.clear(); before loop.

Comment: not working,i want markers automatically update on map

Comment: hello are u there and do u understand my requirement

Comment: I have this problem. Do you find an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Save the instance of all markers which you are going to update and then Remove marker when location gets updated

```
private Marker mCustomerMarker;

if (mCustomerMarker != null) {
            mCustomerMarker.remove();
        }
```

and Re-draw them again

```
     LatLng mCustomerLatLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
     MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
     options.position(mCustomerLatLng);
     options.title(getResources().getString(R.string.pickup_marker));
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.green_pin));
```

Adding the marker in the Google Map

```
mCustomerMarker = googleMap.addMarker(options);
```